# Переместить объект в конец массива, у которого определенная переменная равна 0

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Существует массив объектов.
Для него необходимо написать сортировку по возрастанию (по переменной `getId`) + к этому, если `getId=0`, то необходимо объект перенести в конец массива.
Есть массив:

```
[9,3,0,1,null,null]
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[1,3,9,0,null,null]
```

Разобрался только с сортировкой по возрастанию, но перенести 0 в конец не получается.

```java
public void sortByIN(Student[] students) {
    Comparator<Student> studentComparator = (e1, e2) ->
            Comparator.<Integer>nullsFirst(Comparator
                    .naturalOrder())
                    .compare(e1.getId(), e2.getId());

    Comparator<Student> generalComparator = (e1, e2) -> {
        if (e1 == null || e2 == null)
            return Comparator.nullsLast(studentComparator).compare(e1, e2);
        else
            return studentComparator.compare(e1, e2);
    };
    Arrays.sort(students, generalComparator);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// ноль больше любого другого, остальные равны

Comparator<Integer> zerosLast = (s1, s2) -> {
  if (s1 == 0 && s2 != 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (s2 == 0 && s1 != 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
};
//нули в конце, остальное в естественном порядке

Comparator<Integer> zerosLastAscending = zerosLast.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

//null в конце, остальное в написанном выше поряд
Comparator<Integer> integerComparator = Comparator.nullsLast(zerosLastAscending);
Comparator<Student> studentComparator = Comparator.comparing(Student::getId, integerComparator);
```

Comment: Переписав метод и вставив `Arrays.sort(students,studentComparator);` - выдает ошибку NullPointException. Здесь надо что-то другое использовать вместо `Arrays.sort(..)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Пишем собственный компаратор для сортировки массива `Integer[]`. Сначала идут элементы не равные нулю в обычном порядке по возрастанию, затем элементы `0`, в конце элементы `null`:

```java
Integer[] arr = {9, 3, 0, 1, null, null};

Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.nullsLast((o1, o2) -> {
    int result = Integer.compare(o1, o2);
    if (o1 == 0 && o2 > 0 || o2 == 0 && o1 > 0)
        return result * -1;
    else
        return result;
}));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 3, 9, 0, null, null]
```

Отрицательные числа идут в начале, перед положительными.